# Как в дружественной функции наследуемого класса получить доступ к защищённым данным базового класса

Tags: c++

У меня есть базовый абстрактный класс AcctDMA

```
class AcctDMA
{
private:
    char *label;
    int rating;
protected:
    char* get_label() { return label; }
    int   get_rating() { return rating; }  
public:
    AcctDMA(const char * l = "null", int r = 0);
    AcctDMA(const AcctDMA &rs);
    virtual ~AcctDMA() = 0;
    AcctDMA & operator=(const AcctDMA &rs);
    friend std::ostream & operator<<(std::ostream & os,const AcctDMA & rs);
};
```

От этого класса наследуется класс LacksDMA

```
class lacksDMA : public AcctDMA
{
private:
    enum { COL_LEN = 40 };
    char color[COL_LEN];
public:
    lacksDMA(const char *c = "blank", const char * l = "null", int r = 0);
    lacksDMA(const char * c, const AcctDMA & rs);
    friend std::ostream & operator<<(std::ostream & os, const lacksDMA & rs);
    virtual lacksDMA & operator=(const lacksDMA &rs);
};
```

Конкретно вопрос по дружественной функции класса lacksDMA

```
friend std::ostream & operator<<(std::ostream & os, const lacksDMA & rs);
```

вот её реализация

```
std::ostream & operator<<(std::ostream & os, const lacksDMA & rs)
{
    os << "color: " << rs.color << std::endl;
    return os;
}
```

Как и ожидалось,функция выводит только поле color lacksDMA. 
Я хочу чтобы эта функция так же выводила поля label и rating базового класса AcctDMA. Не могу найти ни одного решения этой проблемы

Я пробовал такой вариант

```
std::ostream & operator<<(std::ostream & os, const lacksDMA & rs)
{
    os << rs.get_label() << std::endl;
    os << "color: " << rs.color << std::endl;
    return os;
}
```

При компиляции я получаю две ошибки

Ошибка Е1086 - объект содержит квалификаторы типа, несовместимые с членом функцию "AcctDMA::get_label(void)"

Ошибка С2662 - char* AcctDMA::get_label(void): невозможно преобразовать указатель this из "const lacksDMA" в "AcctDMA &"

Так же предпринял попытку добавить защищённый метод get_bas_label() в класс lacksDMA. Метод вызывает защищённую функцию get_label() и возвращает её значение. Вот код

```
class lacksDMA : public AcctDMA
{
private:
    enum { COL_LEN = 40 };
    char color[COL_LEN];
protected:
    char* get_bas_label() { return get_label(); }
public:
    lacksDMA(const char *c = "blank", const char * l = "null", int r = 0);
    lacksDMA(const char * c, const AcctDMA & rs);
    friend std::ostream & operator<<(std::ostream & os, const lacksDMA & rs);
    virtual lacksDMA & operator=(const lacksDMA &rs);
};
```

И пытаюсь её вызвать в дружественной функции

```
std::ostream & operator<<(std::ostream & os, const lacksDMA & rs)
{
    os << get_bas_label() << std::endl;
    os << "color: " << rs.color << std::endl;
    return os;
}
```

И получаю ошибку - E0020 индентификатор get_bas_label не определён

Каким образом мне выводить поля базового класса?

Answer (score 1):

- Во-первых, привести в порядок константную корректность (и почитать литературу на эту тему). Ваши функции-геттеры должны быть объявлены `const`

  ```
   char* get_label() const { return label; }
   int   get_rating() const { return rating; }
  ```

  Теперь ваш оператор будет работать в его нынешней форме.
- Во-вторых, я смотрю у вашего базового класса есть свой готовый оператор `<<`.  Может вам надо задуматься о том, а не стоит ли вам просто вызвать оператор `<<` для базового класса из оператора `<<` для наследника, вместо того, чтобы лезть в базовый класс напрямую

  ```
  std::ostream & operator<<(std::ostream & os, const lacksDMA & rs)
  {
      os << static_cast<const AcctDMA &>(rs) << std::endl;
      os << "color: " << rs.color << std::endl;
      return os;
  }
  ```

Comment: Спасибо большое за ответы,несколько часов бился с этим. Теперь я запомню что если объект константный,то можно вызывать только константные методы. Позвольте спросить,а какую тему почитать чтобы понять строчку кода os << static_cast<const AcctDMA &>(rs) << std::endl; конкретно интересует static_cast<const AcctDMA &>(rs)

Answer (score 0):

Ваша проблема не в `friend` а в const корректности. Попробуйте сделать эти функции публичными и получите точно такую же ошибку.

Тот факт что вы используете константную ссылку `const lacksDMA & rs` говорит компилятору что вы не бдутете менять состояние объекта и вызывать неконстантные методы. А вот методы `get_label` и `get_rating` как раз неконстантные, а значит могут менять состояние объекта, следовательно "Ошибка Е1086 - объект содержит квалификаторы типа, несовместимые с членом функцию".

Сделайте так

```
char* get_label() const { return label; }
int   get_rating() const { return rating; }
```

и будет работать.

**PS.** Переключите сообщения компилятора на английский язык